# Ionic: how can I access constructor objects from nested methods?

Tags: ionic-framework, leaflet

I am using leaflet to render a map, and leaflet draw to draw shapes. I am able to draw & save shapes as well as retrieve them. I am struggling how to interact with the retrieved shapes.

In my specific case, I want to init a popover.

**myfile.ts**

```
constructor(public popoverCtrl: PopoverController) {...}

drawShape(data) {
    let shape = {...} // has geometry etc.

    L.geoJSON(shape, {
        onEachFeature: this.onEachFeature
      }).addTo(this.myMap);
}


onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on('click', function (e) {
    let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create('MyComponent', { layer: event });

    popover.present();
});
```

I can't get to `this.popoverCtrl` since it's in a different scope than the constructor. How can I get access to the popover component?

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: I see that your method onEachFeature defines event as “e” then is used as “event” - i didnt fix that in my answer so be careful;)

Comment: Saw that - thank you for catching it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you need to deal with ‘this’ in your case. For that you can use fat arrow functions to do that as they do not create their own “this” unlike anonymous and other functions: see in the layer.on part where i did the change going from anonymous to fat arrow function:

```
onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on('click', event => {
    let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create('MyComponent', { layer: event });

    popover.present();
});
```

Sometimes you will still have issues “getting to” the “this” you need from your component method if you sort of traverse through various execution contexts. In such cases you can also do this trick in your component methods: assign method through variable

```
onEachFeature = (feature, layer) => {
    layer.on('click', event => {
    let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create('MyComponent', { layer: event });

    popover.present();
});
```

This basically prevents your methods from creating their own “this” context.

PS: please note that **your code defines event differently in argument of function and then in the code** (e vs event) i hope you can fix that

Comment: This was extremely helpful! Thank you for your detailed answer!